# R/dplyr filter() can work using grepl function, but can't work using '=='

Tags: dplyr, filter, tidyverse

There is dataframe `test_data` , there are two filter codes, the second can't work . I think they are the same, Anyone can help to explain ? Thanks!

```
# OK 
test_data %>% filter(grepl("Quantit",title))

# Can't work
test_data %>% filter(title=="Quantit\xa8\xa4")
```

[image]

Comment: sample data, please, we can't test against a screenshot

Comment: test_data <- data.frame(title="Quantit\xa8\xa4"),   this is the dataframe, but is should have [quotation marks] in the begin and end, i don't known how to add it to string. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results, for me the results are the same for both expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add quotation marks to a string by 'escaping' them with a `\` before it:

```r
test_data <- data.frame(title="\"Quantit\xa8\xa4\"")


library(dplyr)


# Working `grepl` version to test
test_data %>% filter(grepl("Quantit",title))
#>               title
#> 1 "Quantit\xa8\xa4"

# Using `==` and matching string
test_data %>% filter(title=="\"Quantit\xa8\xa4\"")
#>               title
#> 1 "Quantit\xa8\xa4"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>